# Which preference controls whether multiple selection is available to Package Explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gnome, eclipse-juno, rhel

It used to be the case that if I selected two files (or directories) in Package Explorer, I could then right click and use Compare With -> Each Other.

Recently I have found that my workspaces now only allow either a single file or a contiguous range of file to be selected. In other words, Click...Shift+Click does what I expect, but Click...Ctrl+Click doesn't.

Since this works fine for colleagues working with exactly the same version of eclipse (we all `module load` the same Eclipse deployment) I have to assume that it is a preference of some kind.

Unfortunately, after having gone through the preferences page with a fine tooth comb, I can't see anything which might control this behaviour.

So, can anyone think of a reason why multi-selection may be failing or disables in my explorer, but not that of some of my colleagues?

Note I am working with Eclipse Juno, though I have seen this with previous versions too, on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, using the Gnome Desktop Environment.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts and many failures, I eventually managed to track down this problem.

It seems that if the Gnome preference "Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed" is enabled<sup>†</sup> then multi-selection fails in Eclipse.

#### To fix it, I simply disabled "Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed"<sup>†</sup>.

<sup>† On my Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 installation this is located in: System > Preferences > Mouse > General tab, Locate Pointer section</sup>

The thing which finally gave my a hint was identifying that this was probably due to the same underlying problem as another I was having with the NoMachine NX client, where the nxclient wasn't passing *Ctrl* key presses to the remote end **at all**. See the bug report [Enabling Gnome Accessibility option prevents "ctrl" key from being recognized in NX window](http://www.nomachine.com/tr/view.php?id=TR03G02202)

After my Eclipse Bugzilla account is created,

I have added a bug report for this problem to the Eclipse Bugzilla: [Bug 417573](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417573)